# Regex to find matching pattern

Tags: regex, awk, grep

I need to parse this kind of text:

```
Some text and some 9539 934580 numbers Total number = 45 and then some more text
```

I need to extract this:

Output:

```
Total number = 45
```

with matching spaces...

(NUMBER IS DIFFERENT FROM LINE TO LINE)

How can i get this pattern in a regex?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regular expression is:

```
Total number = \d+
```

or

```
Total number = [0-9]+
```

You can use this with `grep`:

```
grep -E -o 'Total number = [0-9]+' inputfile > outputfile
```

the `-o` option tells it to print just the part of the line that matches.

Comment: how exactly should i use grep or egrep or any other to use this regex?